# Windows sandbox memory limit

Tags: windows-10, memory, virtualization, sandbox, memory-limit

How do I increase the amount of memory available within Windows Sandbox? The default 4GB is not enough for some heavy programs. There seems to be nothing related in .wsb configuration files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `MemoryInMB` configuration node in your `.wsb` file:

```xml
<MemoryInMB>value</MemoryInMB>
```

See also, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-configure-using-wsb-file